# With new Scala 2.11.0 do we still have to use Slick HList to overcome arity limit?

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

Good news, Scala 2.11.0 version has been released. They finally fixed arity limit <22 for case classes
http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2014/04/21/release-notes-2.11.0.html

My question is related to slick orm. Do we still have to use HList to overcome arity limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point there is no production ready Slick version for Scala 2.11.0. Only milestone Slick version 2.1.0-M1 compiles on new Scala.

Slick Table class requires tupled & unapply methods to compile. Those methods does not exists in case classes with arity > 22

So as of April 22 2014 we still have to use HList to overcome arity limits

Thanks to @Régis Jean-Gilles who helped me to unconfuse myself

Comment: The part about `apply` and `unapply` is incorrect. Case classes with arity > 22 *do* have an `apply` method, but given that functions are still limited to a maximum of 22, you cannot lift `apply` into a function (no *eta-expansion* possible). 
As long as you directly call `apply` (as in `MyClass(1,2,3,...)` you are good.
And while there is no `unapply` method, pattern matching still works: the pattern matcher knows how to pattern match a case class by itself, it does not need to call the `unapply` method.

Comment: yes, you're completely right apply. Thank you @RégisJean-Gilles

Comment: No problem. I see you have edited your answer. But wouldn't the fact that you **can** call `apply` and do pattern matching make the sentence "Also apply method restricts functions to 22 parameters" outright irrelevant? Or does Slick needs more (by example would it need to perform eta-expansion on `apply`)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I confused myself. Slick requires tupled && unapply methods to work. Those methods does not exists in case classes with arity > 22

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Any future prospects? This is a major issue holding me back from porting an application from JPA to Slick. Can/should we expect this problem to be properly addressed in the (not so distant) future?

Comment: You still can port your apps to Slick. If you have more than 22 columns in your tables then use HList